# Conditionally show WPF Treeview levels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm using a `TreeView` and `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s in WPF and need to use some logic to decide which level of my data structure should be the root node in the tree.

My data structure that the `TreeView` is bound to is something like this:

```
|Root
|---|Sublevel1
|------|SubLevel2
|---------|Sublevel3
```

Based on the role that the user is logged in as, I need to make the root of the tree one of the sublevels, for example:

- If I'm an *Admin*, show the entire tree as listed above.
- If I'm a *Power User*, start the tree at *Sublevel1*.
- If I'm a *Normal User*, show the tree starting at *SubLevel2*.

What would be the best approach for doing this?  I basically have 4 user roles so I've toyed with the idea of simply creating 4 versions of the tree and selectively showing the correct one based on the user role, but I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If the tree views essentially display the same data, then do not create four separate tree views. That is redundant, keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Populate a single `TreeView` according to the role that is curretly active.

Let us assume that you have a collection in your view model that contains the hierarchical tree data structure. Usually there is a root node or a collection of nodes of a common node data type, which contains an `ObservableCollection` of child nodes.

```
private MyNodeType _root;
```

This root contains the hierarchical data. Expose a property that represents the top level collection of your tree data structure for binding to `ItemsSource` of your single `TreeView`.

```
private ObservableCollection<MyNodeType> _roles;
public ObservableCollection<MyNodeType> Roles
{
   get => _roles;
   set
   {
      if (_roles == value)
         return;

      _roles = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

It is important to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, if you can change roles at runtime, because then you would assign a different collection and without raising the `PropertyChanged` event, the bindings and therefore the associated controls would not update their value.

Now, if you change the role in your application, you can search for matching role in your `_root` member and directly assign the corresponding child collection to the `Roles` property, e.g. `Sublevel1` (assuming that the child collection property is `Children`).

```
Roles = _root.Children;
```

Of course you could also remove the `_root` backing property and load, search and assign the right collection on each user change, that depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed reply.  

So the tree view points to a single root and the root changes based on the user role?  How would the tree know about the data type of the root node since it will change based on the user?